# Iterate through json file to get specific attribute values using python

Tags: python, json

I have a json file as below:

```
[
{
    "contributors": null,
    "coordinates": null,
    "created_at": "Fri Aug 04 21:12:59 +0000 2017",
    "entities": {
        "hashtags": [
            {
                "indices": [
                    32,
                    39
                ],
                "text": "\ubd80\uc0b0\ucd9c\uc7a5\uc548\ub9c8"
            },
            {
                "indices": [
                    40,
                    48
                ],
                "text": "\ubd80\uc0b0\ucd9c\uc7a5\ub9c8\uc0ac\uc9c0"
            }
        ]
    },
    "text": "\uaedb"
    "retweeted_status": {
        "contributors": null,
        "coordinates": null,
        "created_at": "Fri Aug 04 20:30:06 +0000 2017",
        "display_text_range": [
            0,
            0
        ],
        "text": "hjhfbsdjsdbjsd"
    },
    "extended_tweet": {
            "display_text_range": [
                0,
                137
            ],
            "entities": {
                "hashtags": [
                    {
                        "indices": [
                            62,
                            75
                        ],
                        "text": "2ndAmendment"
                    },
                    {
                        "indices": [
                            91,
                            104
                        ],
                        "text": "1stAmendment"
                    }
                ]
            }
    }
}
]
```

I wrote the below python code to count the number of `text` attributes throughout the json file.

```
data = json.load(data_file)
for key, value in data1.items():
    if key=="text":
        cnt+=1
    elif key=="retweeted_status":
        for k,v in value.items():
            if k=="text":
                cnt+=1  
    elif key == "entities":
        if key.keys()=="hashtags" :
            for k1,v1 in key:
# Difficult to loop further
```

Since the data structure doesn't remain constant it becomes difficult to iterate. Further I want to access the value of the `text` attribute and display it. Is there any simpler way to do this without multiple loops?

Comment: `if key.keys()=="hashtags"` will never be `True`, btw

Comment: Why are you looping over the items if you have specific keys? Do something like: `if 'text' in key: cnt += 1` `if 'text' in data.get('retweeted_status', {}): cnt += 1`, etc. No loop necessary.

Comment: @Artyer wouldn't that be difficult in case of  accessing `text` from `extended_tweet` values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about using regular expressions?:

```
import re
regex_chain = re.compile(r'(text)\": \"(.*)\"')

text_ocurrences=[]
with open('1.json') as file:
    for line in file:
        match = regex_chain.search(line)
        if match:
            text_ocurrences.append({ match.group(1) : match.group(2)})
print(text_ocurrences)
```

You get a list of dicts in which each contains key, value of text occurrences

```
[{'text': '\\ubd80\\uc0b0\\ucd9c\\uc7a5\\uc548\\ub9c8'}, {'text': '\\ubd80\\uc0b0\\ucd9c\\uc7a5\\ub9c8\\uc0ac\\uc9c0'}, {'text': '\\uaedb'}, {'text': 'hjhfbsdjsdbjsd'}, {'text': '2ndAmendment'}, {'text': '1stAmendment'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how safe it is to naively parse JSON with regular expression, especially with `(text)\": \"(.*)\"` which could technically match `text": "abc", "text": "another"` with group 1 being `text` and group 2 being `abc", "text": "another`.

It's much safer to parse JSON with python's standard `json` library, then traverse that data recursively.

```
import json

def count_key(selected_key, obj):

    count = 0

    if isinstance(obj, list):
        for item in obj:
            count += count_key(selected_key, item)

    elif isinstance(obj, dict):
        for key in obj:

            if key == selected_key:
                count += 1

            count += count_key(selected_key, obj[key])

    return count


with open("my-json-file", "r") as json_file:
    print(count_key("text", json.loads(json_file.read())))
```